# Laravel: Point laravel subdomain to custom domain

Tags: php, laravel, devops

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.example.com'], function($subdomain)
{
    Route::get('new-lead', 'Home@new_lead');
}
```

I am creating multiple subdomains, and everything is working fine but now I need to point the subdomain to a custom domain for example.

I have created

`xyz.example.com` and now want to point a custom domain on this subdomain.

`xyz.example.com` -> `xyz.com` (or any other custom domain)

Please guide me on how can I point the custom domain to the Laravel subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using redirects:

```php
Route::get('/your-domain', function () {
    return redirect('xyz.com');
});
```

Or if you want to redirect to external webpage, do this `return Redirect::to('www.anyurl.com');`

Resource: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/redirects

Comment: this is only a redirect, i need to point 3rd party domain how can i point on the laravel subdomain this is the issue.

Comment: You can't point 3rd party domain to laravel domain within laravel application. You need to do that on a domain level. You can set up redirects in the dashboard of your domain provider.

Comment: I need support from DevOps and laravel. We need to complete this like shopify.